# II7 URL rewrite - retrieving variables from MySQL

Tags: mysql, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am trying to setup IIS-7 URL-rewrite to take userIDs from a database and re-write them to their username.  For example:

www.website.com/account?id=112233

Needs to rewrite to www.website.com/useraccount

It needs to retrieve the username by doing a MySQL database lookup for that ID.  Is something like this possible?  Is there a guide somewhere online that I can reference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether IIS's rewriting can handle this, but it feels like too big a job for the rewrite module.

Consider sending the request to a script (using whatever server-side language the rest of your site is written in), having that script do the lookup, and doing a header redirect to the new location.

Comment: I thought about doing this - is this going to be SEO friendly?  I wasn't sure if Google would penalize me for this, or if it would help at all.

Comment: @user both ways are equally SEO (un)friendly - IIS's rewriting will do a header redirect, too. There is no other way to change the URL on the user's end. (Just so we are on the same page - you want the URL to change on the user's side, right? Because if you don't, this is a normal rewrite job where you pass 112233 to the receiving script and that does the looking up for you.)

Comment: Cool, that makes it a little more clear.  I haven't actually done something like this before so I'm still a little confused.  Would I create a URL-rewrite rule that sends all requests like www.website.com/useraccount and send it to a PHP processing script that does a database lookup, then re-directs to the actual dynamic URL?  How do I get the SEO friendly URL to appear in the users browser if I'm re-directing to the dynamic?

Comment: @user I think you are looking just for a normal URL rewrite job. The user types in website.com/useraccount. `useraccount` is sent to the PHP script using a normal rewrite rule. The PHP script looks up `useraccount`'s ID and loads the record. I'm not familiar with IIS's rewriting but any basic example will show how to do this (I understood your request a slightly different way at first.)

Comment: Ok, I will look into it.  One last question - Do you think re-writing has a definite SEO benefit?  Seems like a lot of work for something that may not affect ranking.

Comment: @user I'd say it's definitely worth it. Not only for SEO, but for the user experience as well. Clean URLs look.... well, clean. They're possible to memorize and look better when they're passed on. But to answer your question - to my knowledge the presence of keywords in URLs *can* favourably affect search engine ranking, but only if the content matches, too. See also [what are benefits of URL rewriting?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/12453)